# Comparing string values from sequential rows in pandas series

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, apply, shift

I am trying to count common string values in sequential rows of a panda series using a user defined function and to write an output into a new column. I figured out individual steps, but when I put them together, I get a wrong result. Could you please tell me the best way to do this? I am a very beginner Pythonista!

My pandas df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Code": ['d7e', '8e0d', 'ft1', '176', 'trk', 'tr71']})
```

My string comparison loop is:

```
x='d7e'
y='8e0d'
s=0
for i in y:
   b=str(i)
      if b not in x:
          s+=0
      else:
          s+=1
print(s)
```

the right result for these particular strings is 2

Note, when I do def func(x,y): something happens to s counter and it doesn't produce the right result. I think I need to reset it to 0 every time the loop runs.

Then, I use df.shift to specify the position of y and x in a series:

```
x = df["Code"]
y = df["Code"].shift(periods=-1, axis=0)
```

And finally, I use df.apply() method to run the function:

```
df["R1SB"] = df.apply(func, axis=0)
```

and I get None values in my new column "R1SB"

My correct output would be:

```
    "Code"   "R1SB"
0    d7e      None
1    8e0d     2
2    ft1      0
3    176      1
4    trk      0
5    tr71     2
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df['R1SB'] = df.assign(temp=df.Code.shift(1)).apply(
    lambda x: np.NAN
    if pd.isna(x['temp'])
    else sum(i in str(x['temp']) for i in str(x['Code'])),
    1,
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Code  R1SB
0   d7e   NaN
1  8e0d   2.0
2   ft1   0.0
3   176   1.0
4   trk   0.0
5  tr71   2.0
```

Comment: It's beautiful, thanks so much! I digested your code and I think I understand most of it:

line 1: you assign a new variable by creating something like a temporary series for y
line2: use np.NAN to mask the first value of a new column
line 3 is checking for missing values (like NaN in line 2)
line 4: calculates number of common instances between temp and "Code" columns

The only thing I don't get is 1 in line 5. What is it for?

Comment: Line 5 here is the `axis` parameter of the `apply` function. If we pass `1`, it's like iterating over a dataframe row one by one @missmith